# eldoc mode with python appears broken on OS X

Tags: emacs

I recently switched to OS X.  So far I tried running the versions of Emacs from emacsforosx.org, as well as Vincent Goulet's Emacs build. In both of them, the eldoc mode constantly spews output into the Python inferior process, e.g. I see things like the following:

```
emacs.eargs("submission.comments", "import praw\n")
emacs.eargs("r.login", "import praw\n")
_emacs_out
```

I imagine comint is supposed to eat this sort of output before it gets echoed to the buffer, but somehow this is broken. Does anyone have tips on how to troubleshoot this?